# finding textfile name by pattern and moving to newly created folder

Tags: batch-file

I need some help with batch files as I have not done it before. I need to find textfiles with a matching pattern and move them to a class folder. I have a couple of folders that I am browsing through. Can anyone help me to modify the code to move the textfiles together?

This is what i research and piece together.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set file=name.txt
set foldername=class
set location=blockB

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (!file!) do (

set folder=%%a\public\

if not exists "%CD%\!folder!\!foldername!" (mkdir "%CD%\!folder!\!foldername!") ELSE (call)

dir /b "!folder!" | findstr /r /c"!location!"
)
```

my name.txt contains (adam,ben,charlie) 1 name per each line. So technically i want to move text files in (\adam\public) which contains blockB in the textfile name to a newly created folder call class (\adam\public\class). i want it to do the same for (\ben\public) and (\charlie\public). If I have any mistake in the way i code pls pardon me. Thanks.

Reason why I did not use a full path is because I am going to use it on different computers with same folder configurations.

Comment: I think you are getting the name of the file not the contents of the file so Change `for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (!file!) do (`  to `for /f "tokens=* delims= usebackq" %%a in (Qtype fileQ) (` but change Q to backtick

Comment: @Marichyasana, the `for /F` line is fine; `usebackq` is only needed if there are quotes around the name of the file you want to tead the content of...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to accomplish this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "FILE=name.txt"
set "FOLDERNAME=class"
set "LOCATION=blockB"

for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%F in ("!FILE!") do (
    set "FOLDER=%%~fF\public"
    mkdir "!FOLDER!\!FOLDERNAME!"
    move "!FOLDER!\*!LOCATION!*.txt" "!FOLDER!\!FOLDERNAME!\"
)
endlocal
```